Missing Data After Scraping Dynamic Table
Im trying to scrape a dynamic table on a Power BI Dash. Specifically, the 2nd table. Two problems I'm running into. The main issue is that my vertical scraping doesn't collect all of the row data. I'm only able to scrape 248 of the 2k rows or so. The second problem is that when I horizontally scroll, the 9 of the columns are collected as the rest move outside the DOM. I think I'll just run the code twice and not horizontally scroll the 2nd time.
If anyone can help me understand how I can scrape all the rows that would be helpful. I see the table does scroll down to the bottom, so it seems a matter of waiting for the data to load and then scraping it.
 # Initialize the driver, replace with your own setup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, 
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
import pandas as pd
import time

# Initialize the WebDriver and navigate to the URL
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Ensure the table is visible
table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
 'div.tableExContainer')[1]

# Locate the scroll bars
scrolls = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.scroll-bar- 
part-bar')
h_scroll = scrolls[2]  # Horizontal scroll bar
v_scroll = scrolls[3]  # Vertical scroll bar

  # Perform initial horizontal scrolling if necessary
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(h_scroll).click_and_hold() 
.move_by_offset(500, 0).release().perform()
time.sleep(1)  # Allow for loading

all_row_data = []  # List to store all rows data before creating 
DataFrame

# Begin vertical scrolling
previous_row_count = 0
flag = True
while flag:
 try:
    # Wait for rows to be visible and get the current count
    current_rows = 
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located
((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[role='row']")))
    if len(current_rows) == previous_row_count:
        raise TimeoutException("No new rows loaded after 
scroll.")

    # Skip the header row and capture data
    current_rows.pop(0)  # Assuming the first row is the header
    for row in current_rows:
        cells = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
"div[role='gridcell']")
        row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells if cell.text]
        if row_data:
            all_row_data.append(row_data)

    previous_row_count = len(current_rows)  
  # Update row count after processing

    # Scroll down
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(v_scroll).click_and_hold()
  .move_by_offset(0, 100).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)  
 # Allow time for new rows to load

except TimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
    flag = False  # Exit loop if no new rows load
except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
    print("Reached the end of the table or cannot scroll 
further.")
    flag = False
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Encountered an exception: {e}")
    flag = False

# Create DataFrame from collected data
 df = pd.DataFrame(all_row_data, columns=[header.text.strip() for 
 header in table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
 "div[role='columnheader']") if header.text.strip()])

driver.quit()
print(df)


Following code will resolve the issue.
# Initialize the driver, replace with your own setup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
import pandas as pd
import time

# Initialize the WebDriver and navigate to the URL
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(30)
# Ensure the table is visible
table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.tableExContainer')[1]

# Locate the scroll bars
scrolls = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.scroll-bar-part-bar')
h_scroll = scrolls[2]  # Horizontal scroll bar
v_scroll = scrolls[3]  # Vertical scroll bar

  # Perform initial horizontal scrolling if necessary
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(h_scroll).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(500, 0).release().perform()
time.sleep(1)  # Allow for loading

all_row_data = []  # List to store all rows data before creating DataFrame

# Begin vertical scrolling
previous_row_count = 0
flag = True
row_index = 0
while flag:
    try:
        # Wait for rows to be visible and get the current count
        current_rows = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[role='row']")))
        current_rows.pop(0)
        row_index = int(current_rows[-1].get_attribute('row-index')) 
        if row_index == previous_row_count:
            raise TimeoutException("No new rows loaded after scroll.")

        # Skip the header row and capture data
        current_rows.pop(0)  # Assuming the first row is the header
        
        for row in current_rows:
            row_index = int(row.get_attribute('row-index'))
            cells = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='gridcell']")
            row_data = [cell.text for cell in cells if cell.text]
            if row_data:
                all_row_data.append(row_data)

        previous_row_count = int(current_rows[-1].get_attribute('row-index'))
        # Update row count after processing

         # Scroll down
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(v_scroll).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(0, 100).release().perform()
        time.sleep(5)  
 # Allow time for new rows to load

    except TimeoutException as e:
        print(e)
        flag = False  # Exit loop if no new rows load
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
        print("Reached the end of the table or cannot scroll further.")
        flag = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Encountered an exception: {e}")
        flag = False

# Create DataFrame from collected data
df = pd.DataFrame(all_row_data, columns=[header.text.strip() for header in table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='columnheader']") if header.text.strip()])
driver.quit()
print(df)

